# Creating searchBar probleme with css not effecting on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create a searchBar and my CSS but almost everything that I put on it not working, I mean that only colors stuff workings.

```css
.mainBar{
    background-color: blue;
    width: '50rem';
    background: '#F2F1F9';
    border: 'none';
    padding: '0.5rem';
}
```

```js
import './searchBar.css';
const SearchBar = ({ keyword, setKeyword }) => {
  return (
    <input
      className='mainBar'
      key='random1'
      value={keyword}
      placeholder={'search country'}
      onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

so the component have  a blue background but if I'm changing the width nothing happen.

Comment: You should not quote CSS values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the quotes. It should look like this

```
.mainBar{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50rem;
    background: #F2F1F9;
    border: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
}
```